# error: section attribute not allowed when used in macro

Tags: c, gcc, memory, linker

I'm trying to move every declaration of the following macro into another memory segment. It works fine without the section attribute. Any ideas on why I can't use it here, and how I could make it work?

```
 #define RINGBUFFER_DECLARE_MEMB(var, sz) \
                    uint8_t var ## __buf[sz] __attribute__((section(".rambss"))); \                                                             
                    struct ring_buffer var __attribute__((section(".rambss")))
```

> device.h:91:29: error: section attribute not allowed for
>   '__iso_buf__buf'
>        RINGBUFFER_DECLARE_MEMB(__iso_buf, BUF_SIZE_ISOLATED);

Comment: See the expanded  macro using the -E command  line option and you will know what the problem is

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, it works for me (GCC is 7.4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, the problem was that the macro was used in a structure defenition:

```
   struct a { 
      RINGBUFFER_DECLARE_MEMB(umama, 3);     
   };
```

Which is ofcourse not allowed